# Fast App Resume crashing on WP8.1 when not attached to debugger

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a WP8.1 app using MVVM Light. Fast app resume is activated by default which is great as I want to include it in the app.

It works as expected when the app is launched from visual studio. However problems arise when the app is launched directly on the device. The following scenarios result in a crash:

1. launch app from device start menu
2. go out of app (using windows button)
3. go back to the app either via the back button or via the icon in the start menu.

At step 3 the app crashes without any error message.

p.s. I am testing on a Lumia 1520

Best regards,
Tom

Comment: Did you [suspend/resume your app manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/hh974425.aspx) while debugging in visual studio? Your app won't suspend when debugging in Visual Studio unless you manually trigger it to. This should allow you to catch and debug any exceptions.

Comment: Debug Location Resume event does not trigger onActivation event, so it's not possible to debug it that way. onActivation fires when app started from protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your App.xaml.cs, add this code:

```
private bool reset;

private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
    if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
     return;

    RootFrame.Navigating += RootFrame_Navigating;

    RootFrame.Navigated += RootFrame_Navigated;
} 

void RootFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    reset = (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Reset);
}

void RootFrame_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (reset && e.IsCancelable && e.Uri.OriginalString == "/XXXX.xaml")
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        reset = false;
    }
}
```

And in your WMAppManifest.xml, add this code:

```
<Tasks>
  <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="XXXX.xaml" ActivationPolicy="Resume" />
</Tasks>
```