# Login with facebook App in WP8.1 crashes on resume from protocol

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, windows-phone-8.1

I try to implement facebook login whit app in my unity3d game for wp8.1. When debugging in Visual studio everything works fine. App launches from protocol and from onActivated event args i get facebook token. But when i launch game directly from the phone,without VS,sometimes it's not resuming after login, but just restarted. I try to debug OnActivated event in VS using Debug Location Toolbar, but when i choose resume event, onActivated event never fires.
Why it's never restart with visual studio and what can i do to clear this strange behaviour?
My problem described here
[Fast App Resume crashing on WP8.1 when not attached to debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399598/fast-app-resume-crashing-on-wp8-1-when-not-attached-to-debugger)
But the answer is only applyed to wp8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Windows just unloads application from memory. Anyway after last windows update it's happens much rarely