# Windows Phone 8.1: App crashes in fast app switcher when not attached to debugger

Tags: debugging, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have been developing this app for quite a long time, and have had little or no issues. But when I decided to test it without the debugger attached, it caused problems with the fast app switcher. Whenever I switch the app with fast app switcher (or by pressing Start button), it causes the app to crash.

I am using VS2015 and tried enabling break for all exceptions, but still nothing happens while debugging, so I can't understand what the actual problem is.

Any ideas how can I solve this??

P.S. There seem to be a solution for this in this thread: [Fast App Resume crashing on WP8.1 when not attached to debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399598/fast-app-resume-crashing-on-wp8-1-when-not-attached-to-debugger), but it is intended for Windows Phone 8 and doesn't match with the 8.1 api. Any similar solutions for WP8.1??

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to implement the NavigationHelpers in your app ?

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2014/05/23/windows-phone-8-1-frame-page-navigationhelper-suspensionmanager.aspx

I think that may help you :)